# Is it possible to change the background color of comboBox items while viewing them via the drop down list?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am wondering if it is possible to change the Background Color of a series of items in a comboBox. I wish to have the colors for various items change when viewing the list a whole (clicking the little down arrow).

Basically the desired process would go like this:

1) Open form

2) Click on comboBox (*list drops down to display all items*)

3) "Unavailable" items are then shown with a red Background color, while the available ones remain the default color (in this case white).

*Note that no items have been selected yet, only the item list has been shown*

Please let me know if it is even possible to achieve something this specific with the ComboBox control.

Comment: See [ComboBox.DrawItem Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawitem(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The `DrawItem` event is the way to go. One question to ask though is why show unavailable items? Are they valid selections? If they're not valid selections, why show them in the drop down to begin with?

Comment: I'm not able to explain explain exactly what the comboBox items represent, but I'll use an example that will give a similar idea as to what I'm looking for.

Say the items in the ComboBox represent chairs in a classroom. I would like to see all seats, but have the background colors of each item represent whether or not the chair is "open" or not. 

For example, if I was viewing the list of seats and seat 1 was occupied I would like to have the item "Seat 1" background color set to red.

Comment: I hope that makes sense. Remember I wish to only have the background color of the individual ComboBox items changed while I am viewing the entire drop down ComboBox list.